How to extract only unique values from string using regex in Python?
I have this piece of String "Desirable: < 200 Borderline HIgh: 200 - 240 High: > 240" where I want to extract only unique Number or decimal values.
To extract Number,Decimal,- I was using this regex code r'[^0-9.-]+' but it doesn't return unique  values:
import re

check = "Desirable: < 200 Borderline HIgh: 200 - 240 High: > 240"
re.sub(r'[^0-9.-]+', '',check)

output:
200200-240240
Desired output:
200-240
Please Note: Its important to able to extract Numbers, Decimals,- from the string.

You are removing everything that is not a dot, hyphen or digit. Is the structure of the example string important? Or do you just want to match 200 - 240 And what exactly do you mean by unique values?

@Thefourthbird My end goal is to extract Numbers/Decimals as these are Ranges so it it important to have - as well. What I am looking for is Number-Number with unique value structure. Example string is something that I encountered in my actual data but it is just a part of a column from a dataframe.

You can extract all the numbers, decimal numbers using:
re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', check)

Then you can get the unique ones using set() and finally join them using "-".join
Your desired code:
"-".join(set(re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', check)))

One of the challenges of this code is that the set() doesn't preserve the order of numbers. If order matters to you can use numpy.unique() instead:
"-".join(np.unique(re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', check)))

